# Cannot update during an existing state transition - whenever a specific state is changed

Tags: reactjs

I have been getting this error in my component. The error occurs whenever the 'completed' state is changed in any way. The source of issue is in getValidationState() when the state is altered. It does not break my app, however, I am interested to know what I am doing wrong in this component and how I can fix it for the future.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, HelpBlock } from 'react-bootstrap';

class FormGroupValidation extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            completed: false
        };

        this.getValidationState = this.getValidationState.bind(this);
        this.complete = this.complete.bind(this);
        this.unComplete = this.unComplete.bind(this);
        this.toggleComplete = this.toggleComplete.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    getValidationState() {
        const length = this.state.value.length;

        if (this.ThresholdType === 'max') {
            if (this.props.errorLen && length <= this.props.errorLen) {
                return 'error';
            } else if (this.props.warnLen && length <= this.props.warnLen) {
                this.unComplete();
                return 'warning';
            } else if (this.props.successLen && length <= this.props.successLen) {
                this.complete();
                return 'success';
            }
        } else {
            if (this.props.successLen && length >= this.props.successLen) {
                this.complete();
                return 'success';
            } else if (this.props.warnLen && length >= this.props.warnLen) {
                return 'warning';
            } else if (this.props.errorLen && length >= this.props.errorLen) {
                this.unComplete();
                return 'error';
            }
        }
    }
    complete() {
        if (!this.state.completed) this.toggleComplete(); 
    }
    unComplete() {
        if (this.state.completed) this.toggleComplete();
    }
    toggleComplete() {
        this.setState({completed: !this.state.completed});
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <form>
            <FormGroup
              controlId="formBasicText"
              validationState={this.getValidationState()}
            >
              <ControlLabel>Working example with validation</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="text"
                value={this.state.value}
                placeholder="Enter text"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <FormControl.Feedback />
              <HelpBlock>Validation is based on string length. </HelpBlock>
            </FormGroup>
        </form>
        );
    }
}

export default FormGroupValidation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a cycle going.

In your FormGroup JSX you render, you have this property: `validationState={this.getValidationState()}` so when you render, it calls that function. Through subsequent function calls you end up changing the state in your `toggleComplete()` function. When you change the state, it triggers a re-render, and the cycle starts over again (this subsequent render calls getValidationState() to be called and so on)

React is supposed to be reactive ( funnily enough :P ), i.e. the state changes in response so actions.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is a go-er. I'll choose it as an answer when the time limit is up.

Comment: What would be best practice to update the completed state when the input length has exceeded it's limit?

Comment: Do any length checking on FormControl `onChange` functionality so that state changes happen in response to input. Then if their input reaches a certain length, update the state to completed and then stop updating the input on further input (unless they delete stuff)